# CURL > API = no response

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, curl

We're posting from a wordpress form to an API.
Everything we have read so far seems to indicate that this should work.
All CURL config seems to be there and when passing the JSON through Postman, we do get a response.

BUT we do not get a response through this CURL implementation.
Please advise.

```
    add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'CF7_pre_send' );

function CF7_pre_send($cf7) {

$data = array(
        "user" => array(
            "first_name" => "Some",
            "surname" => "Guy",
            "mobile_number" => "0724717299",
            "email" => "someguy@a.com",
            "skype_username" => "john.doe",
            "twitter_handle" => "test.john",
            "linkedin" => "John Matthews Doe",
            "slack_username" => "johndoe",
            "receive_marketing_info" => true,
            "accept_terms_and_conditions" => true,
            "green_member" => false,
            "industry" => "Industry 1",
            "nda" => true,
            "relationship_type" => "Partner",
            "communication_type" => "Newsletter"
        ),
        "company" => array(
            "company_name" => "Test Company",
            "website_url" => "www.test.com",
            "contact_number" => "0211111111",
            "email" => "test@test.com",
            "address_line_1" => "450 Test Strees. Testville",
            "story" => "We specialize in test of testing",
            "service_type" => "Fintech"
        )
);

    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $username = 'USERNAME GOES HERE';
    $password = 'PASSWORD GOES HERE';

    $ch = curl_init("API URL GOES HERE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    file_put_contents("cf7outputtest.txt", $result);

   return $result;
}
```

Comment: try setting a useragent. something like: ` curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try this:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "url-goes-here");
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );

    $result = curl_exec($ch) ;
    if( curl_error( $ch ) )
    {
      echo "Error occurred " . curl_error( $ch );
    }

    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $httpCode != 200 )
    {
        echo "Return code is {$httpCode} \n"
        .curl_error($ch);
    } 
     else {
        echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars( $result )."</pre>";
    }

    var_dump($result);
```

#### NJOY

Comment: Thanks LasVegasCoder - unfortunately your solution did not change the outcome

Comment: @Dayne what is the output of var_dump( $result);

Comment: it was empty/blank

Comment: @Dayne Sorry about that.  Now see the newly edited code, this should work or point you to the error so that we can fix it.

Comment: Error occurred SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificateReturn code is 0 SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

C:\wamp64\www\wp-test\testapi.php:63:boolean false

Comment: @Dayne I edited the code, turned off SSL Verification